# Rocketmq Management console

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, rocketmq

Firstly, wish you all a very happy new year.
Anybody using rocketmq in their projects? Seems like there is no portal or management console kind of thing where we can directly create topics similar to Activemq.  Any idea on this?

Thanks in Advance,
Harinath.

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to [rocketmq-externals](https://github.com/apache/rocketmq-externals)

there is a management console in this project

[image]

Comment: Yes. I have used it. It was helpful.